# How to parse line by line from dmesg in bash?

Tags: bash, read, dmesg

How to parse line by line from `dmesg` command?, i try using a `while` and `read`:

```bsh
while read -r L; do
    echo "line: ${L}";
done < <(dmesg -c --level=err)
```

But can not echo the lines. I try using:

```bsh
LINES=$(dmesg -c --level=err);
while read -r L; do
    echo "line: ${L}";
done <<< "$LINES"
```

But echo only a one line without content.

When call `dmesg -c --level=err` have a 5 lines with content.

How to parse this?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/117549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you forget that `-c` switch is to delete the [dmesg](/questions/tagged/dmesg) content after the first invocation.

It's the simple reason why you don't have line echo-ed.

The first snippet is valid [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) code.

Ensure your default shell is bash !

```
[[ $SHELL == *bash ]] && echo 'bash is the default shell' || echo >&2 "WTF"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was using that argument the wrong way.